# HNQ site icons misaligned

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hot-questions

The little site icons in the HNQ box are misaligned on some sites today. I have cleared cache and checked this out with Firefox, Chrome and Safari, all with the same result.

At a minimum, Puzzling.SE and StackOverflow are affected. Meta is not affected.

Picture of the error:

> [image: misaligned HNQ icons]

Basically, it looks like the sprite image doesn't match the sprite CSS for some reason.

Comment: A similar report on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280870/why-are-my-hnq-site-icons-offset) (which you interacted with) suggests that the issue can no longer be reproduced (comcast fixed their proxy? cache expired?). Can you confirm?